# Excel goal seek

Tags: excel, find

I need some form to find value that minus 18% give me introduced value.

Example:

I have some values:

```
X= 100 [some cel]
%= 18
Y=?

100=Y-18%
```

Find `Y`.

Comment: Have you tried anything (including, but not limited, to Google)?

Comment: i was searching GOAL SEEK but its not working for my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a value in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=A1/(1-0.18)
```

[image]

*Solver* is not needed if algebra will suffice!